Is it off-topic to ask whether the legal community considers law a form of technology?
In Slate's Slow Burn podcast, Linda Hirshman says:

A big achievement for feminism was to bring the social technology of law into the single-family dwelling.

Elsewhere, I have adopted this characterization of law as a form of technology, and I've received some (unsupported) pushback.
I'm curious whether Hirshman's characterization is considered mainstream or radical among the legal community, and wish to ask on Law.SE. Would that be off-topic here?
In case jurisdiction matters, every context relevant to my purposes is the United States.
If it would be on-topic, I'd also welcome any suggestions as to how best to tag it.

@MichaelHall Thanks. I've been following the comments down there, and I agree with Dale's rationale. And now I know there's probably an answer waiting for me to post my full Q. Many thanks for looking out for me, though. :)

Probably a better fit on Philosophy
But it works here too. The philosophy of law is called jurisprudence, so, there’s a tag for you. Jurisprudence, or what law is, is on topic.
